# Static routes no longer working, passing id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had routes like this

/state/arizona/unit/AZ22

I wanted to remove the controller names of STATE and UNIT and get routes like this

/arizona/AZ22

Found this code which worked great

```
resources :states, :except => [:index ], :path => '/' do
    resources :units, :except => [:index ], :path => '/'
  end
```

But now my static paths don't work because it thinks it is a state. I have a list of States on the static pages.

```
Error: Couldn't find State with id=about

Code throwing error : def set_state
         @state = State.friendly.find(params[:id])
      end
```

These are my static page routes

```
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
  root 'static_pages#home'
```

Is there a way to fix the routes? 
Or did I use static pages wrong because I'm feeding a list of states to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routes are matched in the order they are specified.  So, organize your routes as follows and give it a try:

```
root 'static_pages#home'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'

resources :states, :except => [:index ], :path => '/' do
  resources :units, :except => [:index ], :path => '/'
end
```

Comment: Nice. I knew they mattered, but for some reason thought the resources thing always had to go on the top. Now it make sense.

Comment: @Longcreative, but please be cautious with this in that (very unlikely to happen but...) there will never be a state named `contact` or `about`.